# Выпадающее меню на jQuey

Tags: jquery, меню

Есть код, уничтожил пол дня своего времени какие только подобные не использовал. Но лучше их не видеть. Хочу сделать чтоб открывалось меню при нажатии но когда мышку убираю закрывалось меню `mauseout`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
// toggles the refine search field values


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('div.handle').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('div.element').animate({
      height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
      opacity: 'toggle' }, 500
    );

    jQuery(this).toggleClass('close', 'open');
    return false;
  });


  <?php foreach ( $_GET as $field => $val ) : ?>
    jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.handle').toggleClass('close', 'open');
    jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.element').show();
  <?php endforeach; ?>

});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: без html сложно понять ваш вопрос. картинки для дизайнеров - здесь им не место)

Comment: В картинке #2 есть все div которые используют в этом скрипте.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто надо было `.mouseleave`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.handle').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next('div.element').animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 500
        );

        jQuery(this).toggleClass('close', 'open');
        return false;
    });



    jQuery('div.element').mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 500
        );

        jQuery(this).hide();
        return false;
    });


    <?php foreach ( $_GET as $field => $val ) : ?>
        jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.handle').toggleClass('close', 'open');
        jQuery('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.element').show();
    <?php endforeach; ?>

});
```